# How to use aad authentication or managed identity to access resources with torus system in azure?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azureportal, azure-managed-identity

We previously used keyvault and connectionstring to access resources in azure. However it will generate many parameters needed. We want to simplify the process.

We wanted to use aad authentication.

Firstly, we tried certificate-based aad authentication https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/certificate-based-authentication first, it works. But the thing is, in keyvault the certificates are set auto-rotation, but in aad app, we can only manually upload new certificate each time (I know there are methods like VM extension or extra software can do auto renewal, but it's complicated. We just want change configs in azure portal and change service code to access.) In this situation, when certificates becomes more and more, it's not suitable to manually renew each cert in each aad app. I notice in some places it says setting tls/ssl settings which makes auto-renewal, but currently in azure portal, it just can manually upload certificates. Only in function app can do tls/ssl settings.

Secondly, then we notice another one as managed identity. It simply says `azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/");` to get token. But the thing is, current login tenantid is microsoft.onmicrosoft.com, but the resources and the subscriptions are all in prdtrs01.onmicrosoft.com through torus account.
Even I try with `string accessToken = azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", prdtrs01tenantid)` still does not work, saying AADSTS50020: User account '{EmailHidden}' from identity provider '...' does not exist in tenant 'PRDTRS01' and cannot access the application '...'. It seems just cannot get token from prdtrs01 tenantid.

Also, I tried to replace the aad app used in first method with the function app used in second method to do certificate-based authentication. However the function app does not have a clientid, just principalId and user managed identity's clientid. Both ids fail with `ClientAssertionCertificate credential = new ClientAssertionCertificate(clientId, cert);` in certificate-based authentication. It finally says "Client assertion contains an invalid signature. [Reason - The key was not found., Thumbprint of key used by client".

In all, I described several ways we tried, but all failed. Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> AADSTS50020: User account '{EmailHidden}' from identity provider
> '...' does not exist in tenant 'PRDTRS01' and cannot access the
> application

As per this first error , it means that the account you are using to access the application is not a part of the tenant that the application is hosted on.

1. Make the application as a Multi-Tenant Application :
   You can convert the application to accept users from multiple tenants. In this way you can give access to users who are not in your tenant without having to add them to the tenant where the application is in.

Maybe account type is set to Accounts in this organizational directory only.
You may have to change it to Accounts in any organizational directory.

Go to Azure portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Manage -> App Registrations --> your app name -> Supported Account Types

(or)

2. Add the user to the tenant as guest :
   You may need to add the user to the tenant that the application is hosted in. You can follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal#add-a-new-guest-user-in-azure-ad) to add the user with your domain as a Guest User to the tenant. And grant access to the application for the said user.

However, if your authentication call is for specific tenant i.e., https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourtenantname or_id, users from other organizations won't be able to access the application and are required to be added as guests in the tenant specified in the request.
In your case, try to authenticate request like https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations or https://login.microsoftonline.com/common